# Punctation in EditText - Android Nougat

Tags: android, android-edittext, voice-recognition, dictation

Why punctuation doesn't work with voice recognition on EditText? I'm using English and Polish language to dictate - in both languages punctuation doesn't work. I tried "comma", "exlamation mark", "period", "question mark" and Polish equivalents - all recognized as normal text like "comma", etc.

I have up to date GBoard keyboard, system version as well (Android Nougat). Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSpeechInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSpeak"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ico_mic" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/tap_on_mic"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your Activity class

```
  private TextView txtSpeechInput;
    private ImageButton btnSpeak;
    private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtSpeechInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput);
        btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);


        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                promptSpeechInput();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Showing google speech input dialog
     * */
    private void promptSpeechInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Receiving speech input
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                    ArrayList<String> result = data
                            .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```